# Apex code error while executing

Tags: apex

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/MyAccount/*')
global with sharing class wrapper
{
    @HttpGet
    global static String MyAccount()
    {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response; 
        list<Account> acc = [Select name ,Id, (Select Id, lastname from Contacts)From Account limit 10];
        list<Accountw> aw = new list<Accountw>();
        list<ContactW> con= new list<ContactW> ();
        for(Account ac :acc)
        {

        for(contact c :ac.Contacts)
            {
                contactW c1 = new contactW(c.name,c.Email);//17 th line

                con.add(c1);
            }
        Accountw a = new Accountw(ac.id,ac.name,con);
       aw.add(a);   
    }

    return JSON.serialize(aw);
}
class Accountw
{ 
    string Ids{get;set;}
    string Name{get;set;}
    list<contactW> con{get;set;}
    Accountw(String ids,string name,list<contactW> con1)
    {
        Ids=ids;
        Name=name;
        con= con1;
    }
}
class contactW
{
    string cname{get;set;}
    string Email{get;set;}
     contactW(string name ,string  Email)
    {
        cname = name;
        Email = Email;
    }
}
}
```

When I execute this code i get the following error:
          message: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Contact.Name Class.wrapper.MyAccount: line 17, column 1
errorCode: APEX_ERROR

Answer (score 3):

In your select statement you select the fields ID and lastName from Contact

```
Select name ,Id, (Select Id, lastname from Contacts)From Account
```

You then on line 17 go on to refer to the name and email fields from Contact. The error says "row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Contact.Name"

You haven't retrieved the name or the email field in your SOQL query.

Your query should look more like

```
Select name ,Id, (Select Id, lastname, name, email from Contacts) From Account
```

The error message is actually pretty helpful!

Comment: thank you ....but the out put is not as expected :-(

Comment: In what way is the output not as expected? You mean that your error is resolved but your code doesn't do what you thought it was going to?

Comment: ya the error is resolved but i dint get the expected output

Comment: @ManojChandran You need not serialize as JSON in last step.The platform automatically converts to JSON if method is HTTP annotated

Comment: @ManojChandran Return Type can be Account Wrapper Itself .You can return Account Wrapper List and the format will be JSON

Comment: I have changed but im getting error

Answer (score 0):

I got the output for the code that I have mentioned in my question

The correct code is

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/MyAccount/*')
global with sharing class wrapper
{
    @HttpGet
    global static  string MyAccount()
    {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response; 
        list<Account> acc = [Select name ,Id, (Select  name, Email from Contacts)From Account  where ActiveStatus__c=true];
        list<Accountw> aw = new list<Accountw>();

        for(Account ac :acc)
        {
            system.debug('ac1');
            list<ContactW> con= new list<ContactW> ();
            system.debug('newlis:'+con);
            for(contact c :ac.Contacts)
            {   
                system.debug('contact>>'+c);
                contactW c1 = new contactW(c.name,c.email);
                con.add(c1);
            }
            Accountw a = new Accountw(ac.Id,ac.name,con);
            aw.add(a);
        }
        system.debug('the list :'+Json.serialize(aw));
        return Json.serialize(aw);
    }
    global class Accountw
    {
        string Ids{get;set;}
        string Name1{get;set;}
        list<contactW> con{get;set;}
        Accountw(String id,string name,list<contactW> con1)
        {
            Ids=id;
            Name1=name;
            con= con1;
        }
    }
    class contactW
    {
        string cname{get;set;}
        string Email1{get;set;}
        contactW(string name ,string  email)
        {
            cname = name;
            Email1 = email;
        }
    }
}
```